# Next Auth token disappears from session from time to time

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt, google-oauth, next-auth

I have a website built with NextJS.
The authentication is done with Next Auth by Google Provider.
When the user signs in, a token is generated. I set the token on the user session.
I use this token to secure my POST requests. I also have a Python/Django API to feed the website.
My only problem is that from time to time the token just disappears.
As I refresh the page, the jwt callback just starts returning token, user, and account as undefined.
Then, the user needs to sign out and sign in again to get the token.

Here is the code of my **route.js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" + new URLSearchParams({prompt: "consent", access_type: "offline", response_type: "code"});

async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
    try {
        const url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=" + token.id_token;

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        });

        const currentToken = await response.json();

        console.log("Token...");
        console.log(token);
        console.log("Current Token...");
        console.log(currentToken);

        if (currentToken.error === "invalid_token") {
            const urlRefresh = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?" + new URLSearchParams({client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, grant_type: "refresh_token", refresh_token: token.access_token});

            const refreshedResponse = await fetch(urlRefresh, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            });

            const refreshedToken = await refreshedResponse.json();

            return {
                ...token,
                id_token: refreshedToken.id_token,
                access_token: refreshedToken.access_token,
            };
        }

        // In case the token is valid
        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);

        return {
            ...token,
            error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
        };
    }
}

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorizationUrl: GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
            domain: process.env.GOOGLE_DOMAIN,
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        jwt: true,
    },
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ profile }) {
            return profile.email.endsWith("@companyName.com");
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            return baseUrl;
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
            console.log("JWT Token");
            console.log(token);
            console.log("JWT User");
            console.log(user);
            console.log("JWT Account");
            console.log(account);
            if (account && user) {
                token = Object.assign({}, token, {
                    id_token: account.id_token,
                    access_token: account.access_token,
                    user,
                });
            }

            return refreshAccessToken(token);
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (session) {
                console.log("Session Session");
                console.log(session);
                console.log("Token Session");
                console.log(token);
                session = Object.assign({}, session, {
                    id_token: token.id_token,
                    access_token: token.access_token,
                    user: token.user,
                    token: token,
                });
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**How can I make sure the token, user and account on the jwt callback will not disappear after a few times refreshing the page?**